# Rename files according to xml tag contents

Tags: xml, regex, linux, macos, file

I have a huge amount of XML files that I need to rename. They are .plist files.

Within each file are a few tags, like this:

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>Steve Allen</string>
<key>Place</key>
<string>London</string>
```

At the moment, all the files are named with long random numbers, like `659238592496052.record` but I need them to be names according to the Name in the files, like `SteveAllen.record` (without any space).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
for file in *.record
do
  nameline=$(grep -A 1 '<key>Name</key>' "$file" | tail -n +2) # Get line after Name key
  name=${nameline/<string>/} # Remove initial <string>
  name=${name/<\/string>/} # Remove trailing </string>
  name=${name// /} # Remove all spaces
  mv "$file" "$name".record
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment you've posted is not valid xml so let's pretend it looks like this

```
<body>
<item>
<key>Name</key>
<string>Steve Allen</string>
</item>
<item>
<key>Place</key>
<string>London</string>
</item>
</body>
```

Using that fragment as input, this program will rename any number of files given as args
If you saved the program as "myrename" then "myrename file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml" would alter the pathname of file1.xml file2.xml and file3.xml to whatever the first item

The tag being called "key" seems to work in a sightly magical way :/

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;
for $file ( @ARGV[ 0 .. $#ARGV ] ) {

    my $ref = XMLin($file);

    $new_name = $ref->{'item'}->{'Name'}->{'string'};

    rename $file, "$new_name.xml" || warn "couldn't rename $file $!";
}
```