# Renaming XML files according to XML tags contents

Tags: xml, perl

I have a folder full of XML files that all look like this:

```
<Index xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="$APTCUSTOM/doctypes/index-capture/index-capture.xsd">
  <Metadata>
    <DeskEd/>
    <PublicationDate/>
    <History/> 
  </Metadata>
  <CasesReported>
    <IxEntryCR>
      <CaseM>
        <IxCard/>
        <CaseName>Property Investments (Development) Ltd v Byfield Building Services Ltd</CaseName>
        <NameMod/>
        <AltName/>
      </CaseM>
```

What I want to do is use a Perl script to rename all of the files according to the contents of the `<CaseName></CaseName>` tags in each file. So, in this example, I'd like to rename the file to `Property_Investments_(Development)_Ltd_v_Byfield_Building_Services_Ltd.xml`.

The closest solution I've found is in this thread [Rename files according to xml tag contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395131/rename-files-according-to-xml-tag-contents). But, I can't get this to work.

I'm very new to Perl and get the feeling I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. A steer in the right direction would be gratefully received!

The code I've been working with is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;
for $file ( @ARGV[ 0 .. $#ARGV ] ) {

my $ref = XMLin($file);

$new_name = $ref->{'CaseM'}->{'CaseName'};

rename $file, "$new_name.xml" || warn "couldn't rename $file $!";
}
```

Comment: I've been working with this snip, which is from the thread I mention above: `#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::Simple;
for $file ( @ARGV[ 0 .. $#ARGV ] ) {

    my $ref = XMLin($file);

    $new_name = $ref->{'CaseM'}->->{'CaseName'};

    rename $file, "$new_name.xml" || warn "couldn't rename $file $!";
}`

Comment: Apologies, I'm still getting used to embedding code in comments.

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my @allxmlfiles = glob("*.xml");
foreach my $eachxml(@allxmlfiles)
{
 open(IN, $eachxml) || die "File couldn't open: $!";
 local $/; $_=<IN>; my $tmp=$_;
 close(IN);
 if($tmp=~m/<CaseName>([^<>]*)<\/CaseName>/g)
 {
  rename($eachxml, "$1.xml");
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use XML::Simple. Even its documentation tells you so.

Here's how to solve your problem with [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) (run with the file name as an argument):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $file = shift;
my $dom = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => $file);
my $name = $dom->findvalue('/Index/CasesReported/IxEntryCR/CaseM/CaseName');
$name =~ s/ /_/g;
rename $file, "$name.xml" or die "Can't rename to $name.\n";
```

Are you sure there's only single CaseName in the file?

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back to me. There are multiple instances of CaseName in the file. The one I want to grab is nested inside CaseM > IxCard. I don't think I'm quite done making myself look like a chump: when I run this the terminal throws back: XML::LibXML->load: specify location, string, or IO at renamer.pl line 8

Comment: 1) `CaseName` isn't in `IxCard` in the sample XML you gave. 2) The script expects the path to the XML file as an argument.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami. I'm painfully aware that this is going to sound (a) dim-witted and (b) annoying, but how do I express the path as an argument? I'm using a Mac and the files are just sat in my Documents folder

Comment: Sorted! Many thanks to all of you for your help and patience!

Comment: @choroba thanks for supplying that solution. Is there a way I can get the script to run against multiple XML files in one go from the command line (I'm using Terminal on OS X)? The files are all in the same directory and have names that go file1.xml, file2.xml etc

Comment: @DanielH: Just use a loop `for my $file (@ARGV)` or `for my $file (glob 'file*.xml')`.